# how to display woocommerce product tags on single product page.?

Tags: wordpress, tags, woocommerce

I'm looking like a crazy person if there is a way to display the tags of a product on the single product page with woocommerce ( wordpress plugin). I can not find anything about ti and I've been trying to tweak the code, but without success . . .

if anybody has some high lite, it will be wonderful,

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so depending on the WordPress theme you use, they might show automatically (just checked and it works right away with the "official" [Storefront theme](https://www.woothemes.com/storefront/)).

If you're writing a plugin (or a theme) though, you're most likely to want the PHP solution. In that case, according to [this](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html), you should be good to go with the following:

```
global $product; // gets the Product object (correspoding to the single page)
$product->get_tags( $product ); // returns an array with product tags
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770797/display-most-popular-product-tags-in-woocommerce-sidebar-widgets-area), you have to use `get_terms('product_tag')`.