# Display Most Popular Product Tags in WooCommerce sidebar widgets area

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, custom-taxonomy

I found this code (http://devotepress.com/faqs/display-popular-tags-wordpress) and I used the short code ([wpb_popular_tags]) but I do not see any result.

How can I use this code for displaying most popular WooCommerce product tags?

Here is their code:

```
function wpb_tag_cloud() {
    $tags = get_tags();
    $args = array(
        'smallest' => 10,
        'largest' => 22,
        'unit' => 'px',
        'number' => 10,
        'format' => 'flat',
        'separator' => " ",
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'show_count' => 1,
        'echo' => false
    );

    $tag_string = wp_generate_tag_cloud( $tags, $args );

    return $tag_string;
}

// Add a shortcode so that we can use it in widgets, posts, and pages
add_shortcode('wpb_popular_tags', 'wpb_tag_cloud');

// Enable shortcode execution in text widget
add_filter ('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Comment: Try this: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-display-most-popular-tags-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, what do you have to know that you don't know may be: 
Classic WordPress post tags are very different than WooCommerce "Product tags" which have a different custom taxonomy `'product_tag'`.

**So you cant use WordPress `get_tags()` to get the product tags.**

> Instead you should **replace it with `get_terms( 'product_tag' )`** this way:

```
function wpb_tag_cloud() {
    $tags = get_terms( 'product_tag' );
    $args = array(
        'smallest' => 10,
        'largest' => 22,
        'unit' => 'px',
        'number' => 10,
        'format' => 'flat',
        'separator' => " ",
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'show_count' => 1,
        'echo' => false
    );
    $tag_string = wp_generate_tag_cloud( $tags, $args );
    return $tag_string;
}

// Add a shortcode so that we can use it in widgets, posts, and pages
add_shortcode('wpb_popular_tags', 'wpb_tag_cloud');

// Enable shortcode execution in text widget
add_filter ('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> **USAGE** - You will need to:
>
> 1. Add the "text" widget in your woocommerce widget bar area.
> 2. Add in the editor of this "text" widget the short code **`[wpb_popular_tags]`** *(then save)*
>
> **This time you will get All your "most popular" product tags** *(The ones that you have set and enabled for your product)*s.

Tested  in WooCommerce 3+ and perfectly works.

Comment: Thank you very much